# Scrolling of whole page instead of inner div only

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm fiddling with CSS again again...

http://www.kebax.dk/test.php

As you see, the container called `map` is scrolling independently of the rest of the `container`. How can I make the whole page scroll when more content is placed in the `content`?

I have tried using the overflow attribute, but without luck...

**EDIT for future references:**

```
        body {
            background:#000000;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:scroll;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }

        #container{
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 950px;;
            background: yellow;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            overflow:auto;
        }

        #map {
            position:absolute;
            top:80px;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            background:#fff;
            overflow:auto;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }

        #header {
            height:80px;
            width:900px;
            background:#333;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #header h1 {
            color:#fff;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #leftgradient {
            width:50px;
            height:80px;
            float:left;
            background:#096;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#000000), to(#333333));
        }

        #rightgradient {
            width:50px;
            height:80px;
            float:right;
            background:#096;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#333333), to(#000000));
        }

        #toppanel {
            background:#179AE8;
            width:950px;
            height:50px;
        }

        #leftpanel {
            background:#179AE8;
            width:100px;
            height:250px;
            float:left;
        }

        #content {
            background:#099;
            width:850px;
            margin-left:100px;
        }



<div id="container">
    <div id="leftgradient"></div>
    <div id="rightgradient"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <header>    
            <h1>
                Heading
            </h1>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div id="map">
        <div id="toppanel">
            top
        </div>
        <div id="leftpanel">
            lefty
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Lots of text!!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to remove a **boatload** of CSS declarations:

- On `body`, remove: `overflow: hidden`.
- On `#container`, remove: `height: 100%`, `overflow: auto`, `position: relative`.
- On `#map`, remove:

  - `position: absolute`, `left: 0`, `bottom: 0`, `right: 0`, `top: 80px`
  - `overflow-x: hidden`, `overflow-y: auto`.

Now you can scroll the page (tested in Firefox only).

Removing all that stuff possibly broke some certain functionality on your page. Let me know if there is anything, and we can see about finding another way to add back in this missing functionality.

---

To fix the issue in the comments, add:

- `html, body { height: 100% }`
- On `#container`, add `min-height: 100%`.

Now, you can see the yellow background poking out on `#container`. A way to fix this would be to change that yellow to white, and then use a background image exactly like this:

[image]
*(save and use it)*

On `#container`:

```
background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Sp1.png) repeat-y
```

You also need to remove the white `background-color` from `#map`.

Comment: Haha - thanks again thirtydot - you practically answered all my previous questions too ;) And they all work out pretty neat. Problem was, that i had problems with the notorious `height:100%`, and I found an example to go for... But yeah, there's too much spam. Hence why I came here, because I got pretty confused.

Comment: Okay, if you update my test.php - you will see that without content too activate the scroll, the page does not fit to the bottom of the browser window...

Comment: Yup, I thought that might be a problem. Which colour do you want to extend to the bottom of the screen? The white or turquoise? What about the menu on the left?

Comment: The white should go to the bottom... The turquoise div is for the content and all I use that div for is to apply a margin-left of the navigation panel's size.. Does this make sense? :)

Comment: Makes sense, except what about the menu? Should that just stay as it is?

Comment: Yeah the menu could go to the bottom too? But isn't that annoying to make?

Comment: One more question, then I'll do something: there's a nice easy way to make the colours extend to the bottom, but it relies on your columns being comprised of boring solid block colors. Is that acceptable?

Comment: So you mean I can't use custom html colors?

Comment: It just means that your menu colour and the white will be also part of an image. I will be using a technique [like this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), with a `1px` high repeating background image.

Comment: Sure that sounds like a nice trick. I have read about faux columns, but never in-depth.

Comment: Thanks mate. That worked out pretty good. I wish I could give you further credit ^^

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: scroll;` :) give that a whirl

Comment: To which id do you prefer? Because I have tried setting the `container` id to scroll with overflow, but that doesn't scroll with the contents of the #map->#content... :(