# HTML scrollbar not working for all objects on page

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

So I have a basic page with several objects. I can't seem to get the scrollbar to work for all objects on the page.
I've set all objects smaller than the region of the scrollbar defined. However, when I scroll, I am never taken beyond the extremities of the objects.
How can I get a single scrollbar statement to work for all objects on the screen?
is there some kind of JavaScript I need to run which invokes the scrollbar functionality of the web browser itself?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>
body{}
</style>
</head>
<body style = "height: 3000px; width: 3000px; border: 1px solid; overflow: auto;">

    <div id = "Line1Main" style = "position:fixed; top: 290px; left: 25px; width: 2000px; height: 1px; transform: rotate(0deg); border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id = "Line1Main1" style = "position:fixed; top: 270px; left: 25px; width: 2000px; height: 1px; transform: rotate(0deg); border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id = "Line1Main2" style = "position:fixed; top: 250px; left: 25px; width: 2000px; height: 1px; transform: rotate(0deg); border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>

    <div id = "Line1Main" style = "position:fixed; top: 1030px; left: 30px; width: 2000px; height: 1px; transform: rotate(90deg); border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id = "Line1Main1" style = "position:fixed; top: 1030px; left: 60px; width: 2000px; height: 1px; transform: rotate(90deg); border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id = "Line1Main2" style = "position:fixed; top: 1030px; left: 90px; width: 2000px; height: 1px; transform: rotate(90deg); border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>

    <script>
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried sticking similar code up in the style, body section of the page- this didn't work- it only seemed to apply the scrollbar region to the header.
I have also tried the `javascript: scrollbars.visible=true`

Links I've been investigating: [Link1](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/437703/one-scroll-bar-for-two-div), [Link2](https://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/ferd17/one_scroll_bar_for_multiple_divs_grids/), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102820/scrolling-of-whole-page-instead-of-inner-div-only)

Comment: Jscript is Microsoft’s highly deprecated scripting language. You mean JavaScript

Comment: Also you likely need CSS rather than JavaScript - your position fixed  may not do what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

had to replace position: fixed; with position: relative;
thank you @mplungjan

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).